# Woher kommt das Wort (Segel)törn?

Tags: etymology

Bin heute über diese Frage gestolpert, als jemand das als "Turn" schreiben wollte (vom englischen *to turn*). Das Wort "Törn" tönt ausgesprochen wie ein Anglizismus, ich vermute aber eher, es stammt aus dem Mittelhochdeutschen oder dem Holländischen.

Der Duden gibt als Ursprungssprache interessanterweise doch englisch an, schreibt es aber ganz eindeutig auch mit ö und nicht mit u.

**Edit**
Ich ergänze mal: [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/T%C3%B6rn) meint *im 20. Jahrhundert von gleichbedeutend englisch turn → en entlehnt, das über altfranzösisch to(u)rn → fr „Drehung, Wendung“.* Kommt also von Drehung. Dieser Zusammenhang ist nicht offensichtlich, zumal eine *Wende* nicht als Drehung bezeichnet wird (und wenn ich mich nicht irre, heisst die Wende auf englisch Tack, nicht Turn).

Mein altes Universal-Wörterbuch (von 1967) schreibt interessanterweise: **Törn** m (~s; ~s) (e.) Tauwindung; Arbeits-, Wachzeit (in einem ~: ununterbrochen); Aufzug.

Comment: http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/T%C3%B6rn

Comment: Da hatte ich zugegebenermassen nicht nachgesehen. Aber wieso _im 20. Jahrhundert von gleichbedeutend englisch turn entlehnt_? Was hat drehen mit einer Reise zu tun?

Comment: Beim Segeln (insb. gegen den Wind) _kreuzt_ man, also segelt die Route im Zickzack. Alle paar Kilometer (je nach Gewässer) muss man demnach eine _Wende_ machen.

Comment: @Earthling: Hast Du dafür eine Quelle? Erscheint mir möglich, aber die Wende wird nie als Drehung bezeichnet, auch nicht im englischen.

Comment: "Drehung"? Im Englischen, _to turn_ heißt nicht nur "drehen", sondern auch "wenden" (z.B. _to turn around_). Der Segeljargon im Englischen benutzt wahrscheinlich ein spezielles Wort (_tack_, soweit ich das übersehen kann). Auch andere Wörter im Segeldeutsch kommen aus dem Englischen (z.B. "Winsch" von _winch_).

Comment: Ich glaube, man muss das Drehen oder Wenden gar nicht segelspezifisch sehen. Es genügt als Motivation des Begriffes auch, dass man wieder zurückkehrt. Das Wort Tour ist ja ganz parallel gebildet.

Comment: Die Tour kommt auch nicht daher, dass man dort Drehungen veranstaltet, sondern dass es eine Rundreise ist, bei der man am Ende zum Ausgangspunkt zurückkommt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alles was ich dazu sagen kann. Ich will mal eine runde auf dem Boot drehen gehen. I'm gonna take her for a spin.

Or with modern GPS. Turn by turn navigation or - it is your turn now.

Turn would mean Zug. Or to do a certain distance in one go. Eine Segelstrecke in einem Zug absegeln.

The latter seems more plausible to me.

An answer was given here: http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/deutsch/etymologie-toern-antoernen-abtoernen

> Törn Substantiv Maskulinum "Fahrt mit einem Segelboot" peripherer
>   Wortschatz Erkennbar fremd (20. Jh.) Entlehnung.  Entlehnt aus ne.
>   turn, dieses aus afrz. to(u)rn "Drehung, Wendung", aus l. tornus
>   "Drehscheibe, Drechseleisen", aus gr. tórnos.  Ebenso nschw. törn,
>   nnorw. torn; Tour.  Carstensen 3 (1996), 1547. englisch

According to this Torn or Törn literally means tour. Or trip. So it is indeed more like making a move than spinning around, which is not what you do on a boat anyway. Your move, has this question been answered?

Comment: The quotation is useful. The speculation not so.

Comment: I do agree with the dictionary citing greek and french. I do definitely not agree with swedish and norwegian - afaik he cited words mean "thorn" in these languages and it really escapes me how this could be correlated to sailing.....

Answer (score 2):

Im Seemannsvokabular ist ein *Törn* vor allem eine [Schlaufe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rundt%C3%B6rn) im Seil und Grundlage der meisten Knoten. Diese „Umdrehung“ des Seils haben die norddeutschen Seefahrer sicherlich dem Englischen oder Holländischen entlehnt.

Ein *Segeltörn* ist meinem Verständnis nach eine Bootsfahrt, bei der man wieder in denselben Hafen zurückkehrt, also eine „Runde gedreht“ hat. Ich stelle mir dabei eine Route auf der Karte vor, die eine Schleife, also einen Törn vollführt.
Dem widerspricht allerdings, dass es laut  [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segelt%C3%B6rn) auch *Überführungstörns* gibt, bei denen ein Schiff von A nach B transportiert wird.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that someone who undertakes a trip with his sailing boat has to turn after some time to get home again. It is not absolutely necessary that Segeltörn is borrowed from English as the people living on the border of the North Sea in Germany and the Netherlands have a lot of marine terms in common with English. So I am not astonished about the spelling Törn. There are a lot of words German and English have in common (ship, boat, sea, water, sail etc) and nobody would say one language has borrowed from the other. They have been in common since earliest times. English to turn and Low German Törn are nothing but a variant of German drehen, mostly pronounced /dre:n/. If you place r after the vowel you get /*dern/ (the asterisk means I assume this form hypothetically). /*dern/ would easily become Törn or English turn. So one might say German drehen, Törn, and English turn have historically the same source. -  The letter r easily changes its position before or after a vowel. That is a very frequent phenomenon of r, compare German Brett and English board, German ihre Brüste and Dutch haar borsten, German Brunnen and German Born, German brennen and English burn.

PS I have just studied a Low German and Dutch dictionary and did not find Törn. So the view that Törn was borrowed from English must be right. The English word from French tourner. And I found that there is already a Latin word tornus a potter's wheel and Greek tórnos meaning the same.

Comment: You've found some words which are common in English and German, but these are very old ones (and both languages share the same roots, as you know). However for most technical terms (i.e. ship parts) the terms are very different and do often not share the same root, such as tack, sheet, jib...

Comment: @PMF: although also for the technical/ship terminology some words are old and coming from the same roots, e.g. Drift/Trift (http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GT10856)